# difference b/w &JFactory::getDBO() and JFactory::getDBO()

Tags: joomla1.5, joomla-dbo

What is the difference between  `&JFactory::getDBO()` and `JFactory::getDBO()` in Joomla 1.5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is not a Joomla one, but PHP.  In PHP, the ampersand means that instead of assigning the actual value, the value will be [passed by reference.](http://php.net/manual/en/language.references.pass.php)  This is important, because you don't want a copy of the database, you want the global database object.  Thus, one should use `$db =&JFactory::getDBO()`.